# how to test rspec shoulda for custom validation in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails, shoulda

I have a Private methods in my model like the following:

```
  validate :record_uniq

  private
  def record_uniq
    if record_already_exists?
      errors.add(:base, "already exists")
    end
  end

  def record_already_exists?
    question_id = measure.question_id
    self.class.joins(:measure).
    where(measures: {question_id: ques_id}).
    where(package_id: pack_id).
    exists?
  end
```

This methods is more like a `uniqueness` scope thing to prevent duplicate records. I want to know how to write test for  `validate :record_uniq` by using `shoulda` or `rspec`?

### Example of what i tried:

```
describe Foo do
  before do
    @bar = Foo.new(enr_rds_measure_id: 1, enr_rds_package_id: 2)
  end

  subject { @bar }

  it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:record_uniq) }
end
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simple - build an object that fails the validation, validate it, and verify that the correct error message has been set.

For example (if you had a model named City):

```
it 'validates that city is unique' do
  city = City.new # add in stuff to make sure it will trip your validation
  city.valid?
  city.should have(1).error_on(:base) # or 
  city.errors(:base).should eq ["already exists"]
end
```

Comment: if any example would be more appreciated to understand clearly.

Comment: I updated the question, and I used your answer but got an error of `expected 1 error on :base, got 0`

Comment: Then your test is doing it's job. Now make it pass.

Comment: bit confusing... Will try that. Thanks

Comment: If you want to change ```city.should have(1).error_on(:base)``` to using the new```expect``` syntax do it like this:
```expect(city).to have(1).error_on(:base)```

Comment: I believe that the second proposed way to test the errors in this answer should be `city.errors[:base]`

Answer (score 9):

Here's what I would do using RSpec 3 syntax.

```
it 'validates that city is unique' do
  city = City.new('already taken name')
  expect(city).to be_invalid
  expect(city.errors[:base]).to include('already exists')
end
```

Comment: can use `expect(city.errors.full_messages).to/not_to include('full message')`